# Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: TestNGFrameWorkBetaVersionPackage.TestNGFrameWorkBetaVersionClass

Tags: selenium, testng

What might be causing

> java.lang.InstantiationException:
>   TestNGFrameWorkBetaVersionPackage.TestNGFrameWorkBetaVersionClass

Is there an error in this TestNG? Looking for your support.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in your test code.

You have basically added a non default constructor to your listener.  From your screenshot its not clear as to how you are wiring in your listener (The stacktrace indicates that this listener is being wired in, either via a testng xml file or via a service loader mechanism)

Listener objects are automatically instantiated by TestNG via reflection. In those situations, TestNG looks for a default constructor for it to be able to instantiate the listener.

To fix the problem, please add a default constructor also to your listener class.

If capturing screenshots on failure is what you are after, then do the following:

1. Get hold of the current test method's `ITestResult`(which represents the test result for a test method) object by calling `Reporter.getCurrentTestResult()` and then jnject the `WebDriver` instance into the `ITestResult` object by adding it as an attribute using `ITestResult.setAttribute()`
2. Now within the listener, in the `onTestFailure()` method, you can retrieve the webdriver object via the `ITestResult.getAttribute()` call and then use that to capture the screenshot.
3. Dont forget to remove reference to the listener in your test class.

Comment: @user2806141 - Please accept my answer, if it answered your question.